# creating mongoengine class dynamicly from json schema

Tags: python, json, mongoengine, jsonschema

i'm looking for a way to take my json schema and dynamically create a mongoengine class at runtime.

for example: 
the mongoengine class written below

```
class user(Document):
     _id  = StringField(required=False) # mongodb id
     name = StringField(required=True)  # user name
     email= StringField(required=False,regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@mydomain.com$")  # user email
```

will be the same as the dynamically generated at runtime class generated from this schema

```
{
"type":"object",
"properties":{
    "_id"      : {"type":"string"},
    "name"     : {"type":"string"},
    "email"    : {"pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@mydomain.com$"}
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Class or objects of some class?

Comment: i want to create a class

Comment: Agree, this would be really useful. Especially for any ecosystem that uses multiple languages, and uses objects outside of the context of DB storage (the jsonschema can be a single source of truth).

Answer (score 4):

You can create python classes dynamically, like below:

```py
user_properties = { 
   '_id': StringField(required=False), # mongodb id
   'name': StringField(required=True), # user name
   'email': StringField(required=False,regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@mydomain.com$"),  # user email
}
User = type("User", (Document, ), user_properties)
```

The remaining is only convertor from dict with "your schema" provided on input, that will be converted to dict `user_properties` .

Also, here is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63181047/3722635) to similar question "[How to generate a model for a mongoengine Document from an already existing collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63181047/3722635)" which can also help.

Comment: No, because it doesn't use a JSON Schema to create the Document class, as per the question.

Comment: It probably doesn't help that the original question doesn't actually specify a real [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) though :(

Comment: @naught101 author can change `user_properties` to whatever schema he need. If he read it from file - he can just do `user_properties = json.loads(file_content)`. I just showed how to provide that to model. I will not build full framework for him here, as it is Q&A service, not freelance platform.

Comment: @naught101 so what is missing (if still anything)?

Comment: Translation between [JSON Schema's types](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html) and the mongoengine equivalents. As well as validation parameters like minimum and maximum, etc.

Comment: @naught101, this is not freelance service and according to rules you can't expect that somebody will do your homework instead of you. StackOverflow is just about giving a hint about some concrete problem after you investigated it by yourself and still don't know or understand something.

Comment: @naught101 I believe that having this structure you can generate dict you need from any source JSON or even plain text (using functions, loops, conditional operators and other Python stuff). If you can't - please describe your problem here (if it is still related to this question) or in separate question.

Answer (score 1):

The [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) template engine has features that can be utilized to create a mongo class template that populates the property schemas in the class definition based on the type of each property. Then, we generate the desired Python class dynamically using a simple intermediate script that renders this template.
The following is an example illustrating this concept. We start with the following project structure, which has a sample parent folder called *Templates* and three files:

```
Templates\
    - mongo_sample.schema.json
    - mongoclass_template.jinja
    - auto_mongo_class.py
```

Let's explore these files:

**1. mongo_sample.schema.json**:

This is the [MongoDB schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/document-schemas/) document. A consistent schema helps create a standard Jinja template later:

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "required": ["name"],
  "properties":{
      "_id"      : {"type":"string"},
      "name"     : {"type":"string"},
      "email"    : {"pattern":"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@mydomain.com$"}
    }
}
```

**2. mongoclass_template.jinja:**

This is the Jinja template for a Mongo class which will be used to render the desired Python Mongo class in the end. It makes use of the Jinja template language. Here's the reference for the [Template Designer Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/). Here, all we are doing is creating a template that covers all "type" cases and also parameters like "required" and "regex". Notice that a consistent schema is important:

```
from mongoengine import DynamicDocument, StringField, IntField

class Student(DynamicDocument):       
    {%- for prop, val in properties.items() %} 
    {%- if prop in required -%}
    {% set req = True %}
    {% else %}    
    {% set req = False %}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if val.pattern is defined -%}
    {% set patt = val.pattern %}    
    {% else %}
    {% set patt = None %} 
    {%- endif -%}  
    {%- if val.type == "string" -%}
    {{prop}} = StringField(required={{req}}, regex={{patt}})
    {%- elif val.type == "int" -%}
    {{prop}} = IntField(required={{req}})        
    {%- else -%} 
    {{prop}} = StringField(required={{req}}, regex="{{patt}}")       
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor %}
```

**3. auto_mongo_class.py:**

This Python script parses through the JSON schema above to get the properties object, passes the necessary variables to the template `render()` method which will be used while rendering the template and finally writes to a Python file called `models.py` which is the final Mongo class:

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template

with open(r"mongo_sample.schema.json", "r") as schema_json:
    schema_tree = json.load(schema_json)
properties = schema_tree["properties"]
required = schema_tree["required"]
template = Template(open(r"mongoclass_template.jinja").read()).render(properties=properties, \
    required=required)

with open("models.py", 'w') as file_:
    file_.write(template)
```

Now, let's run this script:

```
python auto_mongo_class.py
```

A new Python script called `models.py` will appear in the project folder with the following contents:

```
from mongoengine import DynamicDocument, StringField, IntField

class Student(DynamicDocument):    
    
    _id = StringField(required=False, regex=None)
    
    name = StringField(required=True, regex=None)    
        
    email = StringField(required=False, regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@mydomain.com$")
```